# Write a 3D list in a CSV file

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy, csv

I have a (4, 2, 3) list as shown below:

```
import numpy as np

mylist=[[[1,2,3],
      [1,4,3]],

     [[1,8,3],
      [1,4,3]],

     [[1,3,1],
      [1,4,3]],
     
     [[1,0,3],
      [1,4,3]]]


print("shape of list = \n",np.shape(mylist))
```

I wish to write a csv file that will look as such:

[image]

Can somebody please let me know how can I write the list in above CSV file ?

Comment: `csv is a 2d format

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve? Saving a nested structure to a file? You might be better off with the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).